# MySQL combine PHP cron job SQL's into One Query is it Possible?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have following running on php-cron job as php-script. I would like to know is there a possibility that i can do the same thing in ONE MySQL query on the fly ?

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(`user_to`) AS fav_count , user_to  FROM `users_favorite` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `user_to` ";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die("Error in query:" . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $fav_count = $row['fav_count'];
    $user_id = $row['user_to'];
    $sql1 = "UPDATE user SET fav_count='" . $fav_count . "'
                    WHERE user_id=" . $user_id . " ";
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql1, $db) or die("Error in query:" . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: It certainly is possible, but it will require work. Make sure to post the solution as soon as you have figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `update` with `join` for this:

```
UPDATE user u JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(`user_to`) AS fav_count, user_to 
        FROM `users_favorite` 
        GROUP BY `user_to` 
       ) uf
       ON uf.user_to = u.user_id
    set u.fav_count = uf.fav_count;
```

You might want to consider a trigger to maintain the count in the summary table, if you want it kept up-to-date.  That would be a re-design of this component of your system, however.